# Number theory: Solving $2^n-1\equiv0\pmod{n+1}$.

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

If $n$ satisfies the congruence
$$2^n-1\equiv0\pmod{n+1},$$
then what is $n$? Or if you can't know what $n$ is, then what can be said about $n$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you tried yourself and where did you get stuck?

Comment: A few small solutions are $0$, $2$, $4$, $6$, $\ldots$

Comment: i drew a graph(y=2^x-1/x+1) and i tried to figure out this problem using this form 2^n-1=k(n+1) but failed..

Comment: i want to know general term but it's hard to me

Comment: $n+1=p$ works for any odd prime $p$.

Comment: Using Fermat's Little Theorem for a prime number $p$, we have 

$$2^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$$

Comparing this with your equation, we get 

$n=p-1$ where $p$ is a prime number, or $n=0$ (trivial case, as $a^0=1$, for all real $a$, except when $a=0$.)

Comment: wow!!! thank you guys!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @simsim Could you be a bit more precise as to what you want exactly?

Comment: i just wanted general form of n and i think i learned all about what i needed so thank you!!

Comment: i thought i can get the n's general form (like n=2^a+a+4 a is a natural number) something like that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A number $n$ satisfys $2^n\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ (n+1)\ )\ $, if and only if $n+1$ is a fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$.

In particular, if $n+1$ is an odd prime, the congruence holds. But it can also hold, if $n+1$ is composite, the smallest example is $n=2046$.

Note , that there are infinite many composite fermat-pseudo-primes to base $2$.

Another way to classify the numbers satisfying the congruence : $n$ satisfies the congruence if and only if $n+1$ is odd and $ord_2(n+1)|n$. $ord_2(k)$ denotes the order of $k$ to base $2$. This is the smallest positive number $s$ with $2^s\equiv 1\ (\ mod\ k\ )$

Comment: I think that it is impossible to accept more than one answer, but maybe there is a way.

Comment: lol how did you know that i was trying to accept more than one answer?!?!? but i raise both of you guys points so its okay

Comment: I saw the green symbol jumping :)

Comment: @Peter Just a comment, the smallest composite $n$ that verifies the congruence is $n=340$.

Comment: @EstebanCrespi You are right. I mixed the smallest strong Fermat-pseudoprime to base $2$ (which is $2047$) with the smallest weak Fermat-psuedoprime to base $2$ (which is $341$).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Use [Fermat's_little_theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem) and [Fermat_pseudoprime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_pseudoprime#Definition)

Let $n=p-1$, where $p -$ prime. Then 
$$2^{p-1}\equiv1 (\bmod p)$$

Let $n=p-1$, where $p-$ composite number. Then 
$p \in $ [A001567](http://oeis.org/A001567)